# How to compare table entries in R?

Tags: r

I have two different tables that I got using the `table()` command (on a matrix). The first table has around 200 words and their frequencies of appearance, and the second table has around 400 words and their frequencies of appearance. I want to know how many times each word appeared in the 1st table and the 2nd table (not the total amount of appearances).

Comment: Try `merge(table1, table2, by = "word", all = T)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c("a", "the", "cat", "dog", "money", "dog", "money", "dog", "money")
y <- c("a", "the", "cat", "cat", "cat", "dog", "money", "dog", "money", "women")

xx <- table(x)
yy <- table(y)


xx <- data.frame(xx) # Get it out of the table class
colnames(xx) <- c("word", "table1_freq") # name columns appropriately
yy <- data.frame(yy) # Get it out of the table class
colnames(yy) <- c("word", "table2_freq") # name columns appropriately

pacman::p_load(rowr)
result <- cbind.fill(xx,yy, fill=NA)

# Now to replace the NA's with what you requested in the comment:
result$table1_freq <- as.numeric(result$table1_freq)
result$table2_freq <- as.numeric(result$table2_freq)

result$table1_freq[is.na(result$table1_freq)] <- 0  
result$table2_freq[is.na(result$table2_freq)] <- 0  

result[,1] <- as.character(result[,1])
result[,3] <- as.character(result[,3])
result[is.na(result[,1]),1] <- result[is.na(result[,1]),3]
result[is.na(result[,3]),3] <- result[is.na(result[,3]),1]
result

   word table1_freq  word table2_freq
1     a           1     a           1
2   cat           1   cat           3
3   dog           2   dog           2
4 money           2 money           2
5   the           1   the           1
6 women           0 women           1
>
```

I used `pacman` here, but you could also just install the package normally if you don't have it and use `require` or `library`

Comment: Now suppose that x also had an occurence of the word "bat." I want the words to be aligned when they appear in the table below, so if bat doesn't appear in table 2, it's frequency should show up to 0. How do I do this?

Comment: @A.Manimaran OK it's updated now (the word "women" is only in Table 2). Please feel free to upvote and select this as the solution if it was helpful. :)